# Can a/b - b/a be simplified?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can $\frac{a}{b} - \frac{b}{a}$ be simplified? (it's not necessarily equal to anything just part of a bigger equation? Is there some magic rule here?

There's no relationship between A and B.

Comment: You can combine into one fraction, but I'm not sure this is much better.

Comment: @Jmons: $$ \dfrac{a}{b} - \dfrac{b}{a}= \dfrac{a^2-b^2}{a b} = \dfrac{(a-b) (a+b)}{ab}$$ Is that any better?

Comment: Both your comments are helpful, and I like that you both used the word 'better. I guess this is quite a subjective answer and depends on the situation (and :. the answer might be 'No', its not simplifiable.

With the answer @Moo (and any other straight combining) is it brings in more operations then the original - a/b - b/a is two dividing and one subtraction - the forms you present here are 3 multiplications, a subtraction and a division, or a subtraction, an addition and a multiplication and a division.

Comment: It can be useful to switch to the factored form if you need to study the sign or to solve some equation in integers for instance, it is not all about the number of operations.

Comment: When working with two different terms, each with its own denominator, it is usually helpful to convert the expression into a single fraction with one denominator.  This is what the previous comments have done.

Comment: That's fair - @Moo if you want to put it as an answer, I can accept it for the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write

$$\dfrac{a}{b} - \dfrac{b}{a}= \dfrac{a^2-b^2}{a b} = \dfrac{(a-b) (a+b)}{ab}$$

The issue of it being better probably depends on context.